# SAS-How to format arrays dynamically based on information in one column

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS, and would greatly appreciate anyone who can help me formulate a code. Can someone please help me with formatting changing arrays based on the first column values?

So basically here's the original data:

```
  Category     Name1    Name2.........  (Changes invariably)

  #ofpeople     20       30
  #ofproviders  10       5 
  #ofclaims     40       25
  AmountBilled  50       100
  AmountPaid    11       35
  AmountDed     5        6
```

I would like to format the values under Name1 to infinite Name# and reformat them to dollar10.2 for any values under Category called 'AmountBilled','AmountPaid','AmountDed'.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't conditionally format a column (like you might in excel).  A variable/column has one format for the entire column.  There are tricks to get around this, but they're invariably more complex than should be considered useful.

You can store the formatted value in a character variable, but it loses the ability to do math.

```
data have;
input category :$10. name1 name2;
datalines;
#ofpeople     20       30
#ofproviders  10       5 
#ofclaims     40       25
AmountBilled  50       100
AmountPaid    11       35
AmountDed     5        6 
;;;;
run;
data want;
set have;
array names name:;  *colon is wildcard (starts with);
array newnames $10 newname1-newname10; *Arbitrarily 10, can be whatever;
if substr(category,1,6)='Amount' then do;
 do _t = 1 to dim(names);
  newnames[_t] = put(names[_t],dollar10.2);
 end;
end;
run;
```

You could programmatically figure out the newname1000 endpoint using PROC CONTENTS or SQL's DICTIONARY.COLUMNS / SAS's SASHELP.VCOLUMN.  Alternately, you could put out the original dataset as a three column dataset with many rows for each category (was it this way to begin with prior to a PROC TRANSPOSE?) and put the character variable there (not needing an array).  To me that's the cleanest option.

```
data have_t;
set have;
array names name:;
format nameval $10.;
do namenum = 1 to dim(names);
  if substr(category,1,6)='Amount' then nameval = put(names[namenum],dollar10.2 -l);
  else nameval=put(names[namenum],10. -l); *left aligning here, change this if you want otherwise;
  output; *now we have (namenum) rows per line.  Test for missing(name) if you want only nonmissing rows output (if not every row has same number of names).
end;
run;

proc transpose data=have_t out=want_T(drop=_name_) prefix=name;
by category notsorted;
var nameval;
run;
```

Finally, depending on what you're actually *doing* with this, you may have superior options in terms of the output method.  If you're doing PROC REPORT for example, you can use compute blocks to set the style (format) of the column conditionally in the report output.